# Form data from wordpress theme to be submitted in other site url

Tags: forms

Suppose I have a wordpress site live and it contains a custom form i.e to collect user's data for checkout of the product, but the data collected will be submitted to a given url (e.g., http://example.com) not on the wordpress site itself.

Is it possible? 
What to do?

Comment: Yes, It is possible. And also you need to encrypt data if you are sending it on different url. This answer might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39364501/redirect-form-data-in-encrypted-form-to-another-domain#answer-39404517

Comment: Yes you can. Read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11423682/cross-domain-form-posting

Answer (score 0):

> Cross-domain POSTing, GETing is allowed.

So you can easily use form action as http://example.com.

Ex:

```
<form action="http://example.com">
```

Comment: What hosted in different domain?

Comment: So what is the problem if it is in different domain? for a example you have a form in example1.com. you need to send form data to example2.com. So form of example1.com action will be example2.com. `<form action="http://example.com2" method="post">`. Then you can access form data using  `$_POST['name']` in example2.com. Or have I misunderstand the question?

Comment: You understand it right, I just read some security measure regarding this. But how to get data from other domain?

Comment: You have to just put `$_POST['name']` to get data in other domain. Even it on same domain you can't never trust user input values like `$_POST['name']` or `$_GET['name']`. You have to validate them.